# PHP session variable not working across 2 pages

Tags: php, session, variables

Creating form and trying to carry variables accross two pages to a results page. I have tried $GET and $POST and it works fine from page1.php to results.php, but when I change to $SESSION the variable isn't passed or echo'd on results.php. Here's the php code for page1 which won't even work directly to results! Not sure if there is a problem with my code or possibly the server?
Page 1.php:

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
$name = $_SESSION['name']; 
?>
<FORM action="results.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="questionnaire">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
```

Results.php:

```
<?php session_start();?>

<html>           
    <body>                   
        <?php 
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        echo $name; ?>                               
    </body>           
</html>
```

Comment: where do you assign a value to $_SESSION['name']; ?

Comment: i dont see any place  you assign some value to `$_SESSION['name']` in page1

Comment: It is a text field on page 1, so I want the value of whatever is entered in the text box to passed to results...

Comment: to get the value of name on page 2 you need to access the posted data: `$_POST['name']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try executing following code snippet

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
   {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['name']=$name;
  }
 ?>
  <FORM action="results.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="questionnaire">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
```

Actually in your code snippet value for $_SESSION['name'] was not set .so I have defined value for session variable with posted value from HTML form

Comment: Thanks @Rubin Porwal.. had tried this sytax already - must have been a problem with results!

Comment: Can you please try executing the code snippet now and check if you get any issues while execution of above code snippet

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the closing tag in you form, and you don't have a submit button

```
<FORM action="results.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="questionnaire">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />   
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</FORM>
```

Then in results.php

```
<?php session_start();?>

<html>           
    <body>                   
        <?php 

        $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
        echo  $_SESSION['name']; ?> 
        <br><br>
        <a href="page2.php">page 2</a>  


    </body>           
</html>
```

Then i created this page2.php

```
<?php session_start();?>
<html>
    <body>
        Hi, I am still <?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything is fine in my side.

Comment: @jmill23 once the name in the textbox is saved in the session, it cannot be changed. try unset($_SESSION['name']); first then test it again

Comment: not sure what you mean @ Joem Maranan? The variable 'name' now passes from page 1 to results, but not through page 2?

Comment: @ Joem Maranan just saw your above code...didn't include the result of the html...just the main parts.

Comment: because you are still calling the variable $name From $_POST, to make it sure, just call $_SESSION['name'] in every instance you need it. I never store a session variable in another variable because it is confusing. If you want to use it in a query, there is a way to call it like "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='{$_SESSION['name']}'"

Comment: Thanks @ joem maranan is this correct: <?php session_start();?>
<?php
    $_SESSION['name'];
 ?> this doesn't work?

Comment: check it, I updated my answer in results.php, that will work with no problem. My point is just for me, session variables are different from any other variables. If my answer helped you, you may want to accept this as the final answer. :)

Comment: @jmill23 don't forget the echo in your <?php $_SESSION['name']; ?>, it is still a variable that needs to be echoed

Comment: Thanks @Joem Maranan...don't won to echo 'name' on page 2, want to pass it to results and echo it there. Above code isn't working on page 2?

Comment: @jmill23 Everything is working for me. I edited my answer and create a page 2. It is working. Try it

Comment: @ Joem Maranan thanks, but page 2 comes after page 1! So page 1 links to page 2 then results. Page 2 is not passing 'name' to results.

Comment: Ok, to update... I have successfully got my form passing variables across 4 pages! I used $var= $_SESSION[var] = $_POST[var]; then echo'd the variable of page 4.

Comment: Also, I have worked out how to move back pages and keep the variables stored using: <?php session_cache_limiter('private, must-revalidate');?>

Comment: Where I am now...I have about 200 variables on a 4 page form. It has been a bit tedious defining each variable using var= $_SESSION[var] = $_POST[var]; is there and easier method to post ALL the variables into the session, and is it possible to define the variables in a file which each page can include??? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you inverted your variables at this line :

```
<?php
 $name = $_SESSION['name']; 
?>
```

You probably wanted to do :

```
<?php
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
?>
```

Comment: I have tried various syntaxs: $name = $_SESSION['name']; 
$_SESSION['name']= $name; $name = $_POST['name'] = $_SESSION['name']; None work! Please help - doing my head in!

Comment: I have successfully got my form passing variables across 4 pages! I used $var= $_SESSION[var] = $_POST[var]; then echo'd the variable on page 4. I have about 200 variables on a 4 page form. It has been a bit tedious defining each variable, is there an easier method to post ALL the variables into the session, and is it possible to define the variables in a file which each page can include??? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you assign the name variable to session variable

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
?>
<FORM action="results.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="questionnaire">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Results.php:

```
<?
session_start();
$name = isset($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';

if($name){
$_SESSION['name']=$name;

}
?>
<html>           
<body>                   
    <?php echo $name; ?>                               
</body>           
</html>
```

Comment: there is no need for `if($name)` condition. what if $name equates to false? ie `0`

Comment: page 2 just session_start();echo $_SESSION['name'];

Comment: Damm, pasted the same code on page 2 and it didn't pull though to results? <?php session_start();?>
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['name']=$name;
 ?>

Comment: page 2 is another form, before results, so need to pass variable 'name' from page 1 to page 2 to results...

Comment: page2 no need assign, just use $_SESSION['name'] after session_start()

Comment: if you want to pass by form try <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">

Comment: Page 2 code: <?php session_start();?>
<?php
    $_SESSION['name'];
 ?> Didn't work...

Comment: I have removed the IF statment and it still works ok. @Joe Lee

Comment: Ok, page 1 is now working ok, but when I pass 'name' to page 2 it isn't being passed to results? Page 1:

    <?php session_start();
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $_SESSION['name']=$name;
     ?>
Page 2:

    <?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['name']=$name; 
    ?>

Results:

    <?
    session_start();
    $name = isset($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
    
    ?>
    <html>           
    <body>                   
        <?php echo $name; ?>                               
    </body>           
    </html>

Comment: Also, I have worked out how to move back pages and keep the variables stored using: <?php session_cache_limiter('private, must-revalidate');?>

Answer (score 0):

```
Try....
 Page 1.php : <?php session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
 ?>
  <FORM action="results.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="questionnaire">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

Results.php:

<?php session_start();?>

<html>           
    <body>                   
        <?php 
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        echo $name; ?>                               
    </body>           
</html>
```